# How do I convert a list of entries into a dictionary and merge it with an already existing dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given I have the following function:

```
add_to_list({ 'GOOG': [100.21] }, ('GOOG', 130.00))
```

This function is supposed to convert values **('GOOG', 130.00)** into a dictionary in the format **'GOOG':130.00**. On top, it is meant to append the already existing dictionaries with values that are not already included.

Upon trying the code I stumble upon the issue that I cannot transform the list into a dictionary:

```
def add_to_list(x,y):
    output=list(y)
    dict.output
    return output

    

    
add_to_list({ 'GOOG': [100.21] }, ('GOOG', 130.00))
```

Comment: Do you want to over-write or append the value to the list? Please update your post with the desired output so that it's clear

Comment: Please clarify **exactly** what output you expect by example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a flawed interpretation of the challenge.

```
def add_to_list(x, y):
    assert isinstance(x, dict)
    assert isinstance(y, tuple)
    k, v = y
    x.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return x
print(add_to_list({ 'GOOG': [100.21] }, ('GOOG', 130.00)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'GOOG': [100.21, 130.0]}
```